# Login via Social Network Database Structure

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Can anyone give me some advice or idea, how do i make the user login via Social Networking (Twitter, Facebook, Google Plus, etc) and then recognize and check wether the same user was already registered in the website if not then register them.

Most case possibilities:

1. User registered via email but next time they want to login via
   social networks (how to recognize the same user)
2. User registered via twitter (save user if its new user), but how to check if the same user try login via Facebook or else.

---

```
USER TABLE
user_id  | user_name | user_email | user_pwd

USER_OAUTH TABLE
oauth_id | user_id | oath_type (Twitter, Facebook, etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use HybridAuth it's well written and easy to implement http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/